# notation in r6rs grammar for complex numbers

Tags: numbers, scheme, r6rs

In [r6rs grammar](https://scheme.com/tspl4/grammar.html#./grammar:h0) for numbers there is this rule:

```
<complex r>  => ....  | <real r> @ <real r>
```

If I evaluate in `mit-scheme` the "number" `2@2` I get this strange complex number.

```
1 ]=> 2@2

;Value: -.8322936730942848+1.8185948536513634i
```

I did not find documented anywhere what this rule means, what kind of numbers one can generate with this syntax.  Where could I find some definition of this?  Where this notation comes from?

EDIT:

I found [this link](https://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/ftpdir/scheme-mail/HTML/rrrs-1985/msg00016.html).  The notation dates back to 1985.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [polar notation for complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Polar_complex_plane) <magnitude>@<angle>.  I've never found [documentation for it](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Numerical-operations.html) other than the syntax but I'd guess that <angle> is in radians.

(magnitude 2@2) => 2.
(angle 2@2) => 2.

Comment: `@` seems to be an abbreviation for `make-rectangular`.